# function declaration is described by interface but I can't assign names

Tags: c

I have been given a function interface that looks like this:

```
typedef enum order (*cmp_fun)(const void *x, const void *y);
bool tree_member(cmp_fun, const void *, const struct tree *);
const struct tree *tree_insert(cmp_fun, const void *, const struct tree *);
```

When I try to give the function pointer a name and implement the function I get a compiler error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
bool tree_member(order (*funcptr), const void* test_value, const struct tree* my_tree){... ///?

const struct tree* tree_insert(int (*funcptr), const void* insert_value, const struct tree* my_tree){... //???
```

There is something about the function declaration for accepting the function pointer as a parameter that I am not understanding

```
 In file included from tree-examples.c:21:
tree.c:15:18: error: unknown type name ‘order’
   15 | bool tree_member(order (*funcptr), const void* test_value, const struct tree* my_tree){
      |                  ^~~~~
tree.c:22:20: error: conflicting types for ‘tree_insert’
   22 | const struct tree* tree_insert(int (*funcptr), const void* insert_value, const struct tree* my_tree){
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried many many variations:

```
bool tree_member(cmp_fun (*funcptr), const void* test_value, const struct tree* my_tree){


const struct tree* tree_insert(cmp_fun (*funcptr), const void* insert_value, const struct tree* my_tree){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it doesn't recognize `order` as a type name.  You need to write `enum order` instead of just `order`.

Looking at that part of the code, I noticed you used the wrong type for the first argument of the `tree_member` function.  The interface is telling you that the first argument of `tree_member` must have type `cmp_fun`, but you accidentally made it have type `order *`.

The compiler is also telling you that the `tree_insert` implementation you wrote has the wrong type.  Look carefully at the first argument of `tree_insert`.  It is supposed to be a `cmp_fun` according to the interface, but you accidentally made your first argumet be an `int *` instead.

**Hint:** Instead of typing your function implementations in from scratch, you can simply *copy* the declaration you were given, replace `;` with `{ }`, and add a name for any arguments that are missing a name.  Following this hint, you would get this code as a starting point:

```
bool tree_member(cmp_fun cmp, const void * ptr,
  const struct tree * my_tree)
{
}

const struct tree * tree_insert(cmp_fun cmp, const void * ptr,
  const struct tree * my_tree)
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried the variations you've suggested but it isn't clear to me what the correct answer is. What would you make the implementation declaration look like?

Comment: See my hint and code that I just added above.

Comment: OMG, I feel silly... honestly I thought I had tried this but I think the delay of the syntax error highlighting led me astray... thanks!